# Compact way to filter a vector base on two vectors of position in R

Tags: r, performance, data-manipulation, code-readability

I have a vector of text, e.g.

```
library(stringi)
MWE <- stri_rand_strings(200, 10, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]")
```

My actual example is not random, so I get to find some recurring occurences of pattern I want to keep.
I am therefore able to `grep` the start and the end of my pattern, and get two vectors :

```
sequence_start <- c(9,44,56,73,85,98,110,122,140,152,164,176,188)
sequence_end <- c(14,49,61,78,91,103,115,127,145,157,169,181,193)
```

This is the *easy* pattern, so nearly all of my sequences are of the same length of 5, but 1. one is of 6 and 2. for more general reasons I would like to do from the two vectors mentionned.

My desired output is a sequence of extracts of my MWE based on the aforementioned start and end sequences, i.e. `MWE[9:14], MWE[44:49] etc.`

I can do that with a `for` loop (although I have an warning) :

```
Desired_Output <- rep(NA,length(sequence_start))
for (i in (1:length(sequence_start))){
  Desired_Output[i] = MWE[sequence_start[i]:sequence_end[i]]
}
```

But I try to improve a bit my coding skills, and have understood `for` loops should be avoided as much as possible, so I am wondering what better ways there could be to do that.
I am open as to which format the output is. Ideally, code readability is a factor, as I work with people even less fluent in R than I am !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option without an *explicit* loop is using `Map()`:

```
MWE[unlist(Map(seq, sequence_start, sequence_end))]
```

Unless milliseconds are important I think the loop is fine. But I don't think the current loop is doing what you want? Here is a modification:

```
Desired_Output <- list()
for (i in (1:length(sequence_start))){
  Desired_Output[[i]] = MWE[sequence_start[i]:sequence_end[i]]
}
Desired_Output <- unlist(Desired_Output)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Actually, I think the listed option is better suited for me. How to adapt the first option to get the list result of the second ?

Comment: Maybe `lapply(Map(seq, sequence_start, sequence_end), function(x) MWE[x])` or `lapply(seq_along(sequence_start), function(i) MWE[sequence_start[i]:sequence_end[i]])`

Comment: I guess the second option is a good compromise between efficiency and readability thanks a lot